# How do I give the time duration of listening to python speech recognition library?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am working on RPi 4 and got the code working but the listening time, from my microphone, of my speech recognition object is really long almost like 10 seconds. I want to decrease this time. I looked at the [speech recognition library documentation](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) but it does not mention the function anywhere.

Python editor gives me the following prompt of the `listen()` function;

> self:Recogniser, source, timeout = None,phrase_time_limit = None
> snowboy_configuration =None

So I tried calling the function like:

```
audio = r.listen(source,None,3)
```

Or

```
 audio = r.listen(source,3,3)
```

hoping it will listen for 3 seconds, but it's not working that way.

Following is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

speech = sr.Microphone(2)

#print(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names())

while 1:

             with speech as source:
                 print("say something!…")
                 audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                 audio = r.listen(source,None,3)
                 print("the audio has been recorded")
             # Speech recognition using Google Speech Recognition
             try:
                 print("api is enabled")
                 recog = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-US')
                 # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
                 # to use another API key, use r.recognize_google(audio)
                 # instead of r.recognize_google(audio)

                 print("You said: " + recog)
             except sr.UnknownValueError:
                 print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
             except sr.RequestError as e:
                 print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

**How do I decrease the time duration of listening?**

Answer (score 6):

Try using:

```py
audio = r.listen(source, 10, 3)
```

---

The reason this works is because `r.listen()` takes 4 arguments:

```py
listen(
    source,
    timeout,
    phrase_time_limit,
    snowboy_configuration
)
```

1. `source`:

   > The source audio (an instance of `AudioSource` should be passed here)
2. `timeout`:

   > The `timeout` argument is the maximum number of seconds that this will wait for a phrase to start before giving up and throwing a `speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception
3. `phrase_time_limit`:

   > The maximum number of seconds that this will allow a phrase to continue before stopping and returning the part of the phrase processed before the time limit was reached

By using:

```py
audio = r.listen(source, 10, 3)
```

You're setting `10` as the `timeout` and `3` as the `phrase_time_limit` which is essentially telling Python to:

1. Listen to the user for 10 seconds, and if nothing is said, raise an error
2. Cut the user off (if they're still talking) at 3 seconds

Comment: Welcome to SO. Whilst your code may solve the problem, some explanation as to how it does so is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=3)
```

You can set the `phrase_time_limit` while ignoring the other optional arguments.

Documentation says:

> The phrase_time_limit parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this will allow a phrase to continue before stopping and returning the part of the phrase processed before the time limit was reached. The resulting audio will be the phrase cut off at the time limit. If phrase_timeout is None, there will be no phrase time limit.