# Python voice recognition withou return

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech

I'm trying to follow this example:
https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-speech-recognition-to-convert-speech-to-text-python

I try to follow the example with speech recognition with microphone.
I made this code below:

```
class Voice:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        import speech_recognition as sr

        r = sr.Recognizer()

        print("Recognizing...")
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            # read the audio data from the default microphone
            audio_data = r.record(source, duration=5)

            # convert speech to text
            text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="es-ES")
            print(text)
new_voice = Voice()
```

I just get the  right result when I use `r.record` with a specific duration like 5 sec:

`audio_data = r.record(source, duration=5)`

But I want something similar as the google, that recognize when the user stop to talk.

I tried this 3 others way, but without return:

```
            audio_data = r.listen(source)
            audio_data = r.listen(source, timeout=2)
            audio_data = r.record(source)
```

The terminal doesn't give me any error, it's like it's waiting for me to talk or something.

I fount in the record method documentation:

> Records up to `duration` seconds of audio from `source` (an `AudioSource` instance) starting at `offset` (or at the beginning if not specified) into an `AudioData` instance, which it returns.

> If `duration` is not specified, then **it will record until there is no more audio input.**

However i literally mute the mic after speaking and even then the terminal stayed the same.

Comment: "The terminal doesn't give me any error, it's like it's waiting for me to talk or something." Well, did you try talking? Is the microphone working? *How* do you want the program to determine that you have finished talking?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel like I said, I'd like him to recognize when I'm done talking, maybe when the input volume goes down

Comment: Okay. What if you aren't already talking when the program gets to that point? It should use some similar rule to make sure you *started* talking first? Do you see anything in the documentation about this? How about if you search for information or tutorials? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I search in this 3 topics:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200907/can-i-control-the-start-finish-time-when-i-use-speech-recognition-in-python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200907/can-i-control-the-start-finish-time-when-i-use-speech-recognition-in-python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65641455/how-do-i-give-the-time-duration-of-listening-to-python-speech-recognition-librar

but they didn't solve my problem.